# Path error after opening new terminal

Tags: 14.04

This error message pops up each time I open a new terminal.

```
bash: /home/rabi/.bashrc: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token 'PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH'
bash: /home/rabi/.bashrc: line 11: 'rt PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

on line 11, make sure you have the word "export" not "rt"

Full line should be:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: i can't manipulate it.

Comment: # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;


   * )return;;
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- Did you try to edit it using gedit or vim?

Comment: "sudo nano /home/rabi/.bashrc" I used this command